# Have two different homepages based on customer logged in or not

Tags: magento-1.7

I have set login page as home page using cms page but I want to display login page as home page before login but after login my category page should display as home page how to do this

Answer (score 2):

I would hook into the event `controller_action_predispatch_customer_customer_login`, check wether the user is logged in, if it is the case, throw an exception of the form

```
$e = new Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Exception();
$e->prepareForward('catalog','category','view', array('id' => $categoryId));
throw $e;
```

If the user is not logged in, the default behaviour is used, which is the login form.

How to do it?

## Implement your own module

As @MagikTejas explains in another answer, you need to implement your own Module, by creating a `YourCompany_YourModule.xml` in `app/etc/modules`, but instead of implementing your own route, you implement an observer as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11197771/1480397

Observer are implement inside of the `config.xml` in `app/code/<local|community>/YourCompany/YourModule/etc/`. The question wether you use `community` or `local` depends on whether you want to publish your module (aka use it in more than one installation)

Your config.xml should contain this part:

```
<frontend>
    <events>
        <controller_action_predispatch_customer_customer_login>
            <observers>
                <yourmodule_save_order_observer>
                    <class>YourCompany_YourModule_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>controllerActionPredispatchCustomerCustomerLogin</method>
                </yourmodule_save_order_observer>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_predispatch_customer_customer_login>
    </events>
</frontend>
```

Now you implement your observer, the observer lives in `app/code/<local|community>/YourCompany/YourModule/Model/Observer.php`

The name of the observer is `YourCompany_YourModule_Model_Observer` and it contains the method `controllerActionPredispatchCustomerCustomerLogin`

```
public function controllerActionPredispatchCustomerCustomerLogin() {
    //check wether customer is logged in, if yes, redirect him
    if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
        // you need to get the $categoryId, but this is your part. You could hardcode it (which is a bad idea) or add a configuration setting (just google, how to do it) or something else, this is up to you.
        $e = new Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Exception();
        $e->prepareForward('catalog','category','view', array('id' => $categoryId));
        throw $e;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please give the step to reproduce clearly

Comment: Kindly explain me step by step clearly to proceed

Comment: added more description.

Comment: I have tried above but there is no change my cms login page is default page before and after login ,is there any other step

Comment: Hook with xdebug into the observer, check whether it is called, if not something with the configuration is wrong, if yes, something with the observer is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating a custom module as follows:

Create following directories for the module -

```
/app/code/local/Mycompany/Mymodule
/app/code/local/Mycompany/Mymodule/controllers
/app/code/local/Mycompany/Mymodule/etc
```

To set up a module that will let you redirect an incoming root website link to 
wherever you want, first set up a module xml file under /app/etc/modules/Mycompany_Mymodule.xml containing this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mycompany_Mymodule>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Mycompany_Mymodule>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Create your config file in /app/code/local/Mycompany/Mymodule/etc/config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mycompany_Mymodule>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Mycompany_Mymodule>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <mycompany>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Mycompany_Mymodule</module>
                    <frontName>mycompany</frontName>
                </args>
            </mycompany>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Now, create the controller file in /app/code/local/Mycompany/Mymodule/controllers/PageController.php

```
<?php
class Mycompany_Mymodule_PageController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {       
          if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn())
          {
         $this->getResponse()->setRedirect('catalog/category/view/id/10'); //10 is the category id which you want to display as home page
          }
          else
          {
          $this->_redirect('contacts'); //contacts - is the URL identifier of cms page add you login page identifier here.
          }
    }   
}
```

Now the most important thing to make this work as expected go to **"System > Configuration > Web > Default Pages"** and enter the following for the **"Default web url"** option:

**mycompany/page/**

mycompany/page/ - this will call index action of our custom module.
Hope this will help you.

Comment: I have tried all you said but my page results There has been an error processing your request 

Front controller reached 100 router match iterations

Trace:
#0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/vidhya/wigmore/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(183): Mage::throwException('Front controlle...')
#1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/vidhya/wigmore/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#2 /opt/lampp/htdocs/vidhya/wigmore/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)

Error log record number: 180714953

Comment: I change default  web url from cms to mycompany/page/     is there any need to change cms option

Comment: is there any solution to rectify the above error

Comment: Have you tried clearing cache? What magento version you are using?

Comment: ya  I clear cache Magento ver. 1.7.0.2

Answer (score 0):

To change homepage layout with login layout you can able to do using event **controller_action_layout_load_before**

You can follow below working code:

create one module, add below code in MyCompany/MyModulename/etc/config.xml

```
<events>
        <controller_action_layout_load_before> 
            <observers>
                <mymodulename>
                    <class>MyCompany_MyModulename_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>changeHomepageContent</method>
                </mymodulename> 
            </observers>
        </controller_action_layout_load_before>
    </events>
```

Create observer file in MyCompany/MyModulename/Model/Observer.php

```
class MyCompany_MyModulename_Model_Observer 
{ 
    /**
     * change homepage content
     * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
     */
    public function changeHomepageContent(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
       $fullActionName = $observer->getEvent()->getAction()->getFullActionName();
       if($fullActionName == 'cms_index_index') {
             if (!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) { // check if customer is not logged in                          
                   $layout = $observer->getEvent()->getLayout();
                   $layout->getUpdate()->removeHandle('cms_page');// this will remove existing cms page content.
                   $layout->getUpdate()->addHandle('customer_account_login'); //this code will add login page content to homepage.
            } 
        }


    }        
}
```

I hope above code will help you :)

Comment: BhavsarI have done above two code what is the next step to do

Comment: because after doing this there is no change in my website

Comment: I think you are doing something wrong, as above code is working fine with fresh Magento 1.7.0.2.

Is there any other extension installed?

Comment: My question is there any need to change  "System > Configuration > Web > Default Pages" and enter the following for the "Default web url" option: because in that I have give cms and load login page

Comment: In "System > Configuration > Web > Default Pages" we can set only single page, which will be CMS page by default. I hope you have created module and added above code.

Comment: First of all have you tried to do echo, exit in function changeHomepageContent , is this function is calling or not?

Comment: ya I have created module as you said and added code but this code is not considering it display my cms page only

Comment: no this function is not calling

Comment: can you please paste your config file and observer file code

Comment: while pasting this error occur too long by 249 characters but my observer is similar to above

Comment: public function changeHomepageContent(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
       $fullActionName = $observer->getEvent()->getAction()->getFullActionName();
       if($fullActionName == 'cms_index_index') { if (!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) { $layout = $observer->getEvent()->getLayout();
            $layout->getUpdate()->removeHandle('cms_page');// this will remove existing cms page content.
                   $layout->getUpdate()->addHandle('customer_account_login'); //this code will add login page content to homepage.
            } 
        }


    }

Comment: I have created extension for you, try this with fresh magento and check, is it working for you or not. http://www.files.com/shared/52dcc50c617d0/Magecracker_Restrictpage-0.1.0.zip extension

Comment: ya ok I will try and update my status